# Menu bar of windows explorer in Windows7 is gone

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

If you press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key or check `Organize>Layout>Menu bar` within Windows Explorer, the menu bar is shown.

However, this is not happening for me. When I do either of these, the menu bar does not show.

How can I get it to display?

[image: explorer]

Comment: It seems that Microsoft calls that thing *folder bar* and it shouldn't be able to hide it at all. That of course won't help you at all but if there is a MS official document you should be able to find it using the right name...

Comment: @zagrimsan, it's a menu bar is it not? It's even called a Menu Bar in the context menu

Comment: But the question is saying that ALT does not work... Have I missed the question here?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Either I misread or the question was refined later on. My bad, probably.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Click the Start button, type folder options and click the "Folder Options" link that appears.
> 2. When the "Folder Options" multi-tabbed dialog box appears, click the "View" tab.
> 3. Underneath "Advanced Settings", check "Always Show Menus".
> 4. Click "OK" to close the dialog box.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-explorer-toolbar-is-missing/3dc6e031-38c7-4e0a-b370-6a9a2da54468)

---

> Registry hack
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar
> ```
>
> For Windows Explorer: In the right pane, locate the Explorer sub-key
>   and open it. In the right pane, locate the ITBarLayout value. Right
>   click this value and select Delete.
>
> For Internet Explorer: In the right pane, locate the WebBrowser
>   sub-key and open it. In the right pane, locate the ITBarLayout value.
>   Right click this value and select Delete.
>
> Quit Registry Editor.
>
> Open the affected program (Windows Explorer or Internet Explorer) and
>   verify that you're Menu bar/Toolbar has been restored. If not, close
>   all open Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer Windows and repeat the
>   above step. Then locate the ShellBrowser sub-key, open it and delete
>   the ITBarLayout value there.

[Source](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/117914-45-windows-explorer-toolbar-missing)

Comment: If it is the menu bar indeed, this should be the way to fix things.